# Why Jest is throwing "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" when testing React component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I followed the [Jest - React tutorial](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content) to test a React component.

Unfortunately, Jest throws:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/mishamoroshko/react-playground/src/search-panel/questions/__tests__/questions-test.js: /Users/mishamoroshko/react-playground/src/search-panel/questions/questions.js: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
at Contextify.sandbox.run (/Users/mishamoroshko/react-playground/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:12:24)
at JSDomEnvironment.runSourceText (/Users/mishamoroshko/react-playground/node_modules/jest-cli/src/JSDomEnvironment.js:108:22)
at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/mishamoroshko/react-playground/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:341:23)
```

**To reproduce:**

1. `git clone git@github.com:SEEK-Jobs/react-playground.git`
2. `cd react-playground`
3. `npm install`
4. `npm test`

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I wonder whether the problem is that Jest doesn't know about ES6, and I need to use [`6to5-jest`](https://github.com/6to5/6to5-jest).

Is there a way to specify 2 preprocessors in `package.json`?

```
"jest": {
  "rootDir": "src",
  "scriptPreprocessor": "../preprocessor.js",
  "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
    "../node_modules/react"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33664482/1319850) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, adding [`6to5-jest`](https://github.com/6to5/6to5-jest) solved the problem.

Here is how I implemented multiple `scriptPreprocessor`s in Jest:

```
// preprocessor.js

var ReactTools = require('react-tools');
var to5 = require('6to5-jest').process;

module.exports = {
  process: function(src, filename) {
    return ReactTools.transform(to5(src, filename));
  }
};
```

If you have a better way to implement this, please leave a comment.

Comment: `ReactTools.transform(src, {harmony: true})` would give you some of the simpler parts of ES6 (arrow functions, class, etc.).  Also, 6to5 understands JSX and is run against react's jsx tests.  Unless I'm missing something, ReactTools.transform is just a very expensive noop in your code.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand You are right! I removed `ReactTools.transform` and all works fine. Thanks a lot for your tip!